# Combining variables and PCs to find clusters

Tags: clustering, pca

I am working on a 100 variables dataset, and I am following a recipe for calculating clusters:

- Select only variables that have less correlation, or are below a 10 value in VIF
- Then for the unselected variables apply PCA, extract some of them (until a certain cumulative proportion of variance), so I don't lose those variables
- Then bind the two datasets and apply kmeans.

Ok, I wasn't sure if this recipe makes sense, so I tried with the classic iris dataset. This is my code and the steps taken:

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf <- iris[,1:4]

cor(mydf)
> cor(mydf)
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

Ok, so I should discard Sepal.Length and Petal.Length with a correlation threshold of 50%. I could apply a stepwise VIF just to make sure:

```r
====================================
Stepwise Variance Inflation factor: 
====================================

Step: 1
 var          vif             
 Sepal.Length 7.07272201393954
 Sepal.Width  2.10087167612425
 Petal.Length 31.2614977749216
 Petal.Width  16.0901754199085

removed:  Petal.Length 31.2615 

====================================
Final selected vars and VIF:
====================================
 var          vif             
 Sepal.Length 3.41573308144537
 Sepal.Width  1.30551501806886
 Petal.Width  3.88996082517842
```

Well. It seems that Petal.Length was a good candidate to eliminate. That's my first doubt, and I will choose to take the cor criteria and only have Sepal.Width and Petal.Width

Now I apply PCA to the unselected variables Sepal.Length and Petal.Length. I will choose at least 90% of cumulative variance:

```r
not_selected <- mydf[,c(1,3)]
princomp <- prcomp(not_selected)
> summary(princomp)
Importance of components:
                          PC1     PC2
Standard deviation     1.9136 0.37426
Proportion of Variance 0.9632 0.03684
Cumulative Proportion  0.9632 1.00000
```

It seems that with PC1 I am ok. Now I bind the first dataset and the PC1 variable, and then I try to use the silhouette coefficient to detect the number of clusters:

```r
library(factoextra)
pcas <- as.data.frame(princomp$x)
pca_sel <- pcas$PC1
final_ds <- cbind(mydf[,c(2,4)], pca_sel)
final_ds_scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(final_ds)) 
fviz_nbclust(final_ds_scaled, kmeans, 
             method = "silhouette", nboot = 25) +
  labs(subtitle = "Silhouette method")
```

When I see the suggested clusters (2) it doesn't agree with what we know (3). This is the plot:

[image]

My question is, does this recipe make sense? Should I combine variables with PCs? As my dataset has 100 variables, this recipe seems weak just for the iris dataset. Was it a mistake to combine different scales?

Comment: A strange recipe, indeed, to bind PCs with variables. Either do PCA on all the variables or don't do PCA.

Comment: "doesn't agree with what we know". Iris data contains only two clear clusters. Questionably - 3 clusters.

Comment: hello @ttnphns, I meant that we know Iris has 3 species. That was my doubt, I have been looking for something that backs up this recipe, which I find strange. By the way I appreciate your comments, and any that could clarify this approach. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you seek to find evidence to support the claim that this recipe is useful? Isn't the better move to try to make it fail -- to identify when it doesn't work? I think you've succeeded quite well at one instance of that task.

Comment: Hello @Glen_b, I guess I have some evidence that this recipe suggest 2 clusters for the iris dataset. But, as they say: "when in doubt, ask". I received an interesting comment from ttnphns, but since I see that the next value on the silhouette coefficient is three... that made me doubt. So I came here to see if there's any literature or experienced expert that has combined PCs and variables.

Comment: Alex, the very idea to replace only heavy correlating features with their main PCs or other form of linear combination (including simple averaging) is all right. So I may release my initial notion. Take the simplest example of variables X, Y, Z. X and Y strongly correlate and Z is almost orthogonal to them. Rather than doing PCA on all the three, extracting 2 PCs, one could extract one PC from X,Y, or simply averarage X,Y. Thus we are left with the dataset having Z and that newly constructed feature having replaced X and Y.

Comment: (cont.) But this approach - "do a subdimentional PCA" - I would not expect it to yield subsequent clustering results anyhow strongly different from results obtained on the pair of PCs taken from all the three initial variables.

Comment: In the all-dimension PCA on the three variables of my example, PC1 will represent mostly X,Y and to some extent Z, and PC2 will represent mostly Z and to some extent X,Y. The "subdimensional" PCA's single PC will represent X,Y, while Z remains to represent itself. I don't expect it to make a great difference in respect to clustering.

Comment: Alexis, sorry I misspelled your name

Comment: Hello @ttnphns, that's a great comment when you explain the example of X,Y,Z. So I could just create a new variable from X and Y by an average for example, and then bind the new var to the Z variable... that gives me some ideas to tweak my current problem. Regarding the iris dataset example, you mentioned that it could be questionably 3 clusters (which in the case of iris could be the species). Could be there any problem when combining the scales of the new PC and the existing selected variables?